# NestJS: How to make friends 2 modules - ServeStaticModule(Angular) and SwaggerModule

Tags: angular, swagger, nestjs

How to make friends SwaggerModule и ServeStaticModule.
I have Angular PWA in the "public" directory:

```
    ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'public'),
      exclude: ['/api*'],
    }),
```

And for now my routing works predictably:

- localhost:6060 - shows SPA(Angular)
- localhost:6060/api - endpoints for PWA

I added SwaggerModule to main.ts:

```
  const prefix = app.get(ConfigService).get('PREFIX') || 'api';
  app.setGlobalPrefix(prefix);

  const config = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('App')
    .setDescription('REST API documentation')
    .setVersion('1.0.0')
    .addTag('docs')
    .build()
  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config);
  SwaggerModule.setup(`${prefix}/docs`, app, document);
```

I want to see the Swagger documentation page if we open URL `localhost:6060/api/docs`, but Angular opens all the time. If I comment ServeStaticModule code, the Swagger page is shown.

How can I resolve this problem... I want this:

- localhost:6060 - shows SPA(Angular)
- localhost:6060/api - endpoints for PWA
- localhost:6060/api/docs - generated page by Swagger

Comment: Why not change the port for NestJs ? keep 6060 for angular app & 6061 for example for the swagger doc ? 

I think locally at least, you should boot your angular app on one port and your nestjs on a different port

Comment: Angular already is built and put to the 'public' directory inside NestJS project